# How can I color the white corner with webkit-scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, webkit

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8quw3/)

I am using `::-webkit-scrollbar` to make a custom scrollbar in Chrome. I have a `border-radius: 10px` and in doing that, there are white corners at the top:

[image: It's kinda hard to see]

Sorry, it's kinda hard to see since it's a scrollbar.

I want the corners to be the same color as the header div (`#dadae3`). Is there any way to get rid of the white corners using CSS only without changing the styles of the scrollbar?

CSS (entire):

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 13px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aeaeb5
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #dadae3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aeaeb5
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #c4c4cc
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background: #aeaeb5
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style='background: #dadae3; width: 100%; height: 30px;'></div>
<div style='width: 100%; height: 1000px'></div>
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You have to set the `::-webkit-scrollbar-corner` pseudo-element, e.g.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner { background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }
```

Comment: This should be accepted: even if it's 1+ year late, it soved the same problem for me in chrome 43

Comment: thank you. Even though I abandoned this project, it's still very helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `background-color` property for the pseudo-element `-webkit-scrollbar`, doing that you can set the "corner color".

Comment: Yes, this works. But when You scroll down, it shows the `#dadae3` against the white. Would I set the `background-color` to transparent?
Edit: No, I wouldn't put the `background-color` as transparent. This also shows as white corners.

Comment: It's already transparent (try giving a background color to fiddler's output iframe), but remember: it's a scrollbar. If something goes behind it, it triggers scrolling, so there cannot be something behind it.

Comment: Ok, I doubt anyone would notice gray corners on a scrollbar. P.S. This is probably going on a live site soon (as soon as I get my server working >:D)

Answer (score 1):

I was fighting this scrollbar-corner today, which takes space and creates unneeded gap. If I use `overflow: auto` on container this scrollbar corner completely disappears while scrollbar itself remains visible.

Answer (score 0):

I had to customize `webkit-scrollbar-corner` as colored triangle instead of square.

Here is the result how to do it. With border trick.

[image]

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background: transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 16px solid #8B7E79;
    border-top: 16px solid #8B7E79;
    border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
    border-right: 16px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background: transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 16px solid #8B7E79;
    border-top: 16px solid #8B7E79;
    border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
    border-right: 16px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. Hidden in the dev tools, I found pseudo: `::-webkit-scrollbar-track`. If set, make sure it's set to the colour you need. If not, set it to the colour that you need to match the background of the modal or container etc. which it services.