# On creating a double scroll with custom css style there is a little white square on the corner. How can I make it invisible?

Tags: html, css, scroll

As you can see in the image below I have a web component that has a scroll in x and other scroll in y direction, so when I give them a custom css style there is this white square in the bottom-right corner that looks bad and my question is: How can I make it disappear? Thanks!

[image]

Fun fact: As I was adding the code snippet I realized that stackoverflow or my web browser is overwriting my scroll style and making it look better. That would be it, but idk how to reproduce it on my project.

[image]

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: pink;
}


/* width */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: .5rem;
  height: .5rem;
}


/* Track */

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: red;
}


/* Handle */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 5em;
}


/* Handle on hover */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I color the white corner with webkit-scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232873/white-corners-webkit-scrollbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`::-webkit-scrollbar-corner`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar).

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: pink;
}


/* width */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: .5rem;
  height: .5rem;
}


/* Track */

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: red;
}


/* Handle */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 5em;
}


/* Handle on hover */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
</div>
```